# Continuity of linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm currently doing my real analysis reading on the continuity of linear transformations, and the book makes this statement:

If $\mathbb{R}^l \rightarrow^{S} \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow^{T} \mathbb{R}^n$ then $||TS|| \le ||T||||S||$

where $||T|| = sup{|Tx|:|x| \le 1}$

But doesn't provide a proof or any statement on the claim. What I don't understand is how two linear transformations enacted right after another can be said to have any properties with each other. The only traits you can deduce from seeing two linear transformations enacted back to back is that the range of one is the domain of the other. How does (what looks like) the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induced norm of an operator $A$ is defined as $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Ax\|$. In particular, this means $\|Ax\| \le \|A\| \|x\|$ for all $x$.

So, you have $\|Ty\| \le \|T\| \|y\|$, and $\|Sx\| \le \|S\| \|x\|$, so letting
$y=Sx$, we have $\|T(Sx)\| \le \|T\| \|Sx\| \le \|T\| \|S\| \|x\|$.

Hence if $\|x\| \le 1$, you have $\|TSx\| \le \|T\| \|S\|$, and so $\|TS\| \le \|T\| \|S\|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify for any bounded linear map that $|Tx|\le \|T\|\cdot|x|$ for all $x$. Using this, for all $|x|\le 1$, we have
$$
|TSx|\le \|T\|\cdot |Sx|\le \|T\|\cdot\|S\|\cdot |x|\le \|T\|\cdot\|S\|
$$
implying the supremum over such $|x|\le 1$ is also at most $\|T\|\cdot\|S\|$, so $\|TS\|\le \|T\|\cdot\|S\|$.